# Return entity type when using table per type inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Lets say I have the following entities

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
}
```

Is it possible to determine the type of entity without creating an instance.

```
var id = 1;
var type = context.Animals.GetTypeOfAnimal(id)

public static Type GetTypeOfAnimal(this ObjectSet<Animal> source, int id)  
{
    // What shall I do here, I dont want to fetch the instance at this point...
    var animal = source.First(a => a.Id == id);
    return animal.GetType();
}
```

One solution I thought about using the following method...

```
public static Type GetTypeOfAnimal(this ObjectSet<Animal> source, int id)  
{
    var info = source.Where(a => a.Id == id).Select(a => new {IsDog = a is Dog, IsCat = a is Cat}).First();

    if(info.IsDog) return typeof(Dog);
    if(info.IdCat) return typeof(Cat);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: The design smells a little as well; querying the specific subtype of a generic type and then branching off that should probably be replaced with polymorphism.

Comment: At the point of your comment, source has already been fetched. Is that what you are trying to prevent? EDIT: No now I see. Thinking time now.

Comment: @millimoose We are currently using polymorphism however we are experiencing some problems with the Entity Framework, it is performing pretty slowly using this type of inheritance.

Comment: Your statement sounds a bit like: "I want to know which type it is, but I dont want to look at it to find out". A bit of a paradox ;)

Comment: EntityFramework has a very bad support inheritance and interface.. You can try the EntityFramework 5, although I'm not sure that this improved.

Comment: @PhilipDaubmeier Very true. I was hoping I could look at the meta data used by the entity framework.

Comment: @J. Lennon: that may be due to a relational database doesnt know anything about inheritance. The EntityFramework as an ORM just kind of 'emulates' this.

Comment: @Rohan West: but how can the framework know about the metadata of a specific instance without fetching the instance?

Comment: Thinking time over but edit time has passed, you still have to go to the database to find the type, even if you don't fetch. So you might as well fetch to prevent re-fetching in the case where it is the type you want.

Comment: In may case two trips to the database will probably be quicker than one fetch,

Comment: @Michael: thats what I thought, too. I'm not sure about the internals of EntityFramework, but the type information is stored somewhere in the database, perhaps inside a column of the animals table, so you have to fetch the instance anyhow.

Comment: @Rohan West: I really doubt solution #2 you just posted will be any faster than #1. What leads you to that conclusion? (Just curious)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get this information without query to database. You are using TPT - it means that database contains Animal, Dog and Cat tables. The inheritance in database is modeled through one-to-one relation between Animal and Dog and between Animal and Cat. The minimum what you have to do is query both Animal and Dog tables for that Id (it can exist only in one of them). The first problem is that you cannot query these tables directly with EF because EF can work only with whole entities (not only with parts mapped to single table) - you must use direct SQL. The second problem is fragility of this solution. If you add new derived entity you must fix this query (same happens for your example).

The reason why TPT queries are slow is that EF must query all inheritance tree = in your case `Animal` joined with `Dog` concatenated with `Animal` joined with `Cat`. There are some performance improvements in .NET 4.5 for querying TPT inheritance tree but it will not affect your query because it simply has to query whole structure.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: can you avoid this penalty by using a projection that only makes use of properties defined in `Animal`?